# Compare tag with branch

Tags: azure-devops

is it possible in Azure DevOps Web Cliet to compare the current content of a given branch with a given tag within the same repository?
Of course I could create a tag in the branch, then compare both tags and finally delete the last tag again but that is inefficient and will lead to forgotten tags.

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to have sth similar to `git diff`?

Comment: `git diff TAG BRANCH`

Comment: In the end I want to have a git diff TAG BRANCH in the web client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do a branch compare, you can click `Tags` and select the tag directly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for.